# How to delete row from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `UITableViewController`. It has data from array of files from Document Directory. I want to delete row this method `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()`
 but I make it, file is deleted but row is not disappeared. I tried several method but they didn't help me. I make it many once with data from CoreData. But I don't know how make it here. Please help me.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            let currentSong = listOfMP3Files[indexPath.row]
            println(currentSong)
            let directory = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
            let url = directory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentSong)
//            println(url)
//            println(indexPath)
            fileManager.removeItemAtURL(url, error: nil)
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPath) as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {

        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
        default: break
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            break
        default: break
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }
```

The second variant

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            let currentSong = listOfMP3Files[indexPath.row]
            println(currentSong)
            let directory = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
            let url = directory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentSong)
//            println(url)
//            println(indexPath)
            fileManager.removeItemAtURL(url, error: nil)
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a line to call `removeAtIndex()` which removes the item at specified index from datasource array

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
listOfMP3Files.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) //Add this line 
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```